# multi type drilldown linked charts using fusioncharts

Tags: javascript, charts, data-visualization, fusioncharts

I am having some issue related to fusioncharts drilldown using multi charts types on same div. My requirement is :

1. I want to display a year report using type='mscolumn2d' on top level, this will be having linked drilldown to months reports and then days reports and finally time reports etc
2. when the users clicks on the year reports(used mscolumn2d chart),it drillsdown to months reports
3. when the user clicks on months report , it drills down to day report
4. when the user clicks on the day report, it should drilldown to the time reports(minutes/hours) in gantt chart.

   I am able to achieve from step 1 to 3, but I am not able to achieve the drilldown of the days chart to time chart(in Gantt charts). Because when we declare a type(eg: mscolumn2d), we can only declare one type of chart, but I need two charts working together mscolumn2d and gantt charts with drilldown mechanism.

   I would appreciate if someone help me or guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using configureLink() method to change chart type on drill down.

Check out a demo fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/qLzxu5dv/

```
yourchart.configureLink({
        "type": "gantt"
    }, 0);
```

Know more about configureLink() here:
http://docs.fusioncharts.com/FusionCharts.methods.html#configureLink